# categorize question by modules

Tags: discussion, tags

so it make it easy to replace D.SE with module issue or even add related question inside issue link in Drupal module page.

I think its useful, is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already categorize questions by modules; that is why there are tags such as [cck](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cck), [panels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/panels), [rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views).

As for replacing *Drupal Answers* with a module issue queue, the purpose of *Drupal Answers* is not replacing the issue queue on Drupal.org, but provide a repository of Drupal questions to which future readers can be interested. That is why questions about bugs are not accepted: They would be not interesting for future readers, once the bug is fixed.

As for linking questions related to a module, you can simply use the link to the tag feed, such as https://drupal.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rules&sort=newest. The feed URL is generally in the format `https://drupal.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=[tag]&sort=newest`.